# ocaml: Basic syntax for function of several arguments

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I am learning OCaml and I'm a complete beginner at this point. I'm trying to get used to the syntax and I just spent 15 minutes debugging a stupid syntax error.

`let foo a b = "bar";;
let biz = foo 2. -1.;;`

I was getting an error `This expression has type 'a -> string but an expression was expected of type int`. I resolved the error, but it prompted me to learn what is the best way to handle this syntax peculiarity.

Basically OCaml treats what I intended as the numeric constant `-1.` as two separate tokens: `-` and `1.` and I end up passing just 1 argument to `foo`. In other languages I'm familiar with this doesn't happen because arguments are separated with a comma (or in Scheme there are parentheses).

What is the usual way to handle this syntax peculiarity in OCaml? Is it surrounding the number with parentheses (`foo 2. (-1.)`) or there is some other way?

Answer (score 4):

There is an unary minus operator `~-.` that can be used to avoid this issue: `foo ~-.1.` (and its integer counterpart `~-`) but it is generally simpler to add parentheses around the problematic expression.

Comment: You can also cut some parenthesis by using the `@@` infix operator.
`foo 2. @@ -1`